# Could covariant tensor fields which are **not** alternating be integrated across a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

In differential geometry, we study the integration of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), which are **alternating** covariant tensor fields. "Alternating" means that swapping two inputs leads to a sign change. For example, $dx\wedge dy=-dy\wedge dx$.

I understand why we need the linear form to be alternating to perform integration - if we consider Jacobian determinants of functions $U\to\mathbb R^n$ (where $U\subseteq \mathbb R^k$ is open), we will notice that as a determinant, swapping two rows leads to a sign change; so according to this, exterior forms are also expected to have this property.

However, I am still wondering if non-alternating forms could be somehow integrated. Consider the 2-form $\omega=dx\otimes dy$, defined explicitly by $\omega(a\partial_x+b\partial_y)=ab$. ($\partial_x,\partial_y$ are orthonormal basis vectors of the tangent space $T_p\mathbb R^2$.) Could we *somehow* make sense out of the integral
$$
\int_{\partial B(0,1)} \omega \text{  ?}
$$
I feel it hard to explain clearly why this would/would not be possible.

Comment: If you change coordinates, say even by rotating, do you get the same answer?  And what you wrote for your explicit definition is no good: You have to feed *two* tangent vectors to this $2$-tensor. Note that if you feed in $\partial_x,\partial_y$ you get $1$ (and then integrate the function?), whereas if you feed in $\partial_y,\partial_x$ you get $0$.